# How to access a Laravel project different machine

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am doing a Laravel project. I have to provide REST API from my project for mobile app. But my problem is how can we access Laravel project from different machine using IP address because Laravel using virtual host. When I was using Codeigniter, I can easily access like `10.0.1.9:8080/myproject` from different for `localhost:8080/myproject`. My current Laravel project URL is `laravel.bbc:8080/`. So how can I access it from different machine? I am using Laravel 5, xampp and my operation system is Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use static DNS resolve. For Windows there is file in system32 folder, usually `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Append following line to it:

```
192.168.1.1 laravel.bbc
```

Where `192.168.1.1` is IP of your Laravel server.

Comment: I already append this line to hosts file 127.0.0.1  laravel.bbc . But how can I access it from url ? when I access like this "127.0.0.1  laravel.bbc" from url it is performing like searching from google because address bar cannot treat it as url .

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem . The problem was I also having old laravel project . It is also working on virtual . So when I access my new project , it keep mapping to old project . So I removed virtual host of old project . So now I am able to access my project like this 10.0.1.9:8080 . It is working . The topic Jan Zahradník mentioned is also important .

Comment: Kindly give @Jan Zahradnik an up vote because answered provided is correct